# Unreal Engine 4 Viewport is Black/Blue

Tags: unreal-engine4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCSz5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQtz6.png)

Please see the pictures in the link above.

I'm new to unreal engine. I've been trying to get Unreal Engine 4 to work on my linux machine ( 5GB RAM & 500GB Harddisk) but I couldn't get the viewport to work. It always shows blue or black screen.

Please I need assistance. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am also a UE4 user / game dev and use *nix.  Usually the behavior you describe happens when there is a video display issue.  In Window this is usually the Nvidia Game Ready driver, sometimes new updates break things, there is a common fix involving a registry edit called *mpo_disable.reg* - anyway, you are not using Windows, just for anyone else who lands here via Google-Fu.

In your case I would say it could be related to the video drivers. Which distro / kernel and video driver are you running? Nvidia card?